# Update the existing array values in a Document in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I want to update the subject field that starts with **http://test** and consists of  **/base** in the value with the value without **base**

for example "http://test/timespan/base/1",  as it starts with https://test and has base in it. Then i want to update it to http://test/timespan/1

so at last the subject array becomes :

"subject": [
"http://test/concept/114",
"http://test/timespan/1",
"http://wikidata/1233"
]

Document sample

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "1233"
  },
  "type": "Entity",
  "subject": [
    "http://test/concept/114",
    "http://test/timespan/base/1",
   "http://wikidata/1233"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a conditional update, like so:

```
db.collection.updateMany({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      subject: {
        $map: {
          input: {
            $ifNull: [
              "$subject",
              []
            ]
          },
          in: {
            $cond: [
              {
                $regexMatch: {
                  input: "$$this",
                  regex: "http:\\/\\/test.*base"
                }
              },
              {
                $replaceAll: {
                  input: "$$this",
                  find: "base/",
                  replacement: ""
                }
              },
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```